# Executing a function on page load, ANGULAR 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple function, checking the width of the window and according to that value it stretches the content. But when I resize the page and reload the site, nothing happens until I resize the window. How do I call a function on page load in angular2?

My whole `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class appComponent {

  private checkScreenWidth() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1000 && window.innerWidth > 499) {
      ...
    } else if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Call it in `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`? Have you read up on the lifecycle hooks? What have you tried?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just tried to call it in component, but didn't work as it supposed to. I will check on google ngOnInit and will let u know bout the progress.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe It works, thank u.

Answer (score 2):

You may import and implement the `OnInit` interface of angular2 core library and define its `ngOnInit` method after implementing the interface in the class. I guess it will do the job.

```
export class appComponent implements OnInit {
  private checkScreenWidth() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 1000 && window.innerWidth > 499) {
      ...
    } else if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkScreenWidth();
  }

}
```

Comment: on init function runs during page loads

Comment: @DhireshBudhiraja That's what he needs: 'How do I call a function on page load in angular2?'  Read the question. Your downvote is unjust!

Answer (score 0):

First of all import OnInit from '@angular/core'module and then call a method inside ngOnInit which you want to call on load its like ng-init from angularjs.

```
import  { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 ngOnInit() {
    this.checkScreenWidth();
  }
```